# INNER JOIN is not working, i do not get errors

Tags: php, sql, select, inner-join, echo

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN `table2`
ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`id`;");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
  echo 'name <textarea>'.$row["name"].'</textarea>';
}
```

on LAb (wampserver) its working i get information about "name", but on really website i not get infromation about "name" .

Comment: If it's not working on the live site, I can almost guarantee you *are* getting errors - but they're not being displayed. Are you successfully connecting to the database? What's the *actual* value of `$conn` ?

Comment: SELECT table2*, table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN `table2`
ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`id`

Comment: Don't use `select *`.  If both tables have columns with the same name, then it is unclear which value you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May some error occur but aren't displayed.

First I suggest you to check the connection:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user "my_password", "$DBname");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

If it works, check for query errors:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN `table2`
ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`id`;"))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
      echo 'name <textarea>'.$row["name"].'</textarea>';
    }
}
else echo($conn->error);
```

Other possible causes may are:

- ON clause

  it's true the condition:

  ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`id`

  or it should be something like this?

  ```
  `ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`rif_id`
  ```
- no data to select in `table1` or `table2`

  In the `live` database did you check if there are data to select? May happens to forget to insert data in the live database.

Also, did you tried the query manually in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: thanks , its working.  also i done mistake, Unicode was not same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you trying to collect, but you can use below query to get the record. it will work for you.

"Select t1.* from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
ON t1.id=t2.id"

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection may be live connection is different. Also remove semicolon(;) after table2.id. May be your problem is resolved